# How to write multiple path and file of a folder in once command line argument dos batch

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, cmd, arguments

On windows 7 x64 with a batch files (*.bat):

I need to check in a folder the last file (less than 5 days) and path to add in Mycommand as argument.

I need i think :

"FORFILES -5"
perhaps "Call"

i begin with :

```
@echo off
REM

set folder="D:\temp"
set vararg="-a"
cd /d %folder%
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b') do (D:\stockage\Mycommand %vararg% %folder%\\"%%i" -v > c:\temp\test_log.txt)
```

How to output like that :

D:\stockage\Mycommand -a D:\temp\file.jpg -a D:\temp\file2.jpg -a D:\temp\file3.jpg etc...

don't put non existing file or blank argument, i think i must Loop the argument "-a D:\temp\filexxx.jpg" but i don't know how to do it.

And if possible escape file name probleme more than x chars or space inside.

Can you give me an example ?

Thank.

Comment: you write "the last file", but your example says three files plus "etc...". Do you mean all files younger than 5 days?

Comment: thank Stephan yes, i mean the youngest files of the directory or the last files create in this directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo` produces a linefeed and you can not stop it from doing so. As an alternative, first assemble the complete line:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set commandline="D:\stockage\Mycommand"
set maxfiles=5
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /o-d') do (
  set /a maxfiles-=1
  set commandline=!commandline! -a "%%i"
  if !maxfiles! leq 0 goto :enough
)
:enough
echo %commandline%
```

This gives you the latest 5 files (or fewer, if the folder has not enough files)

**Edited** to reverse the order of the Parameters:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "commandline="
set maxfiles=5
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /o-d') do (
  set /a maxfiles-=1
  set commandline=-a "%%i" !commandline!
  if !maxfiles! leq 0 goto :enough
)
:enough
set commandline="D:\stockage\Mycommand" %commandline%
echo %commandline%
```

Comment: work fine now i need to sort in reverse order try dir | sort /R don't work then with forfiles /p path /m %extfilters% /d +%yLocal% how to sort i have an other order ? i try set %%i=dir | sort /r > dir-s nothink work...

Comment: they are sorted by date-time. That's neccessary to get the latest five. If you want to reverse the order of the last five, just build the commandline from tail to nose. See my edit.